# Angular frequency of a rolling wheel attached to a horizontal spring at its centre

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Find the angular frequency of a rolling wheel attached to a horizontal spring at its centre.

I found this problem at http://people.cedarville.edu/employee/gollmers/phys2110/images/phys13_60.pdf.

They have solved the problem using energy considerations but I want to know if the problem can be solved using only torques and forces.

Comment: What do you think and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acceleration of the wheel's center of mass will be
$$
M \ddot{x} = -kx + F_c
$$
where $F_c$ is the horizontal component of the contact force between the wheel and the table. The angular acceleration about the center of mass will be given by
$$
\frac{1}{2} M R^2\alpha = F_c R 
$$
(note that the spring force doesn't exert a torque about the CM). Finally, if the wheel is rolling without slipping, we must have
$$
R \alpha = - k \ddot{x}
$$

Combining the second and third equations yields 
$$
F_c = - \frac{1}{2} M \ddot{x}
$$
and plugging this in to the first equation, we obtain
$$
\frac{3}{2} M \ddot{x} = - kx. 
$$
This can be seen to be a harmonic oscillator with an angular frequency given by $\omega^2 = 2k/3M$, which agrees with the result found via the energy method.

Comment: Please don't answer homework problems or questions otherwise against Physics.SE policy.

Comment: @heather This isn't a homework problem. As stated in my post, this is a problem I found online and was curious about.

Comment: @Thomas as our homework policy says, it isn't actually just *homework*, but it's homework-*like* problems.